# JPA query on field on @Mappedsuperclass

Tags: java, jpa

I have a mapped super class below:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "VERSIONABLE_TYPE")
public class Versionable extends VMAuditedObject implements Serializable,
        Comparable<Versionable> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Min(0)
    @Column(name = "major_version")
    private int majorVersion;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Min(0)
    @Column(name = "mid_version")
    private int midVersion;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Min(1)
    @Column(name = "minor_version")
    private int minorVersion;
...
}
```

And an Entity extending it:

```
public class Project extends Versionable {
....
}
```

How could I make a query on the fields defined on Versionable?

```
"select from project "
                    + "where major_version=" + p.getMajorVersion()
                    + " and mid_version=" + p.getMidVersion()
                    + " and minor_version=" + p.getMinorVersion();
```

I get the following error:

```
Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "MAJOR_VERSION" not found;
```

Comment: That probably means that the column MAJOR_VERSION doesn't exist. I think you're abusing inheritance. This should be an embeddable class, not a superclass.

Comment: It does exist as defined in the super class. Also the method shows for the Project class.

Comment: The message doesn't complain about a missing field or a missing property of your class. It comes from the database driver, and complains about a missing **column**.

Comment: This is a hql query or native query? If it's a hql, could you try using the attributes instead of the colluns names? For exaple, instead using major_version use majorVersion. You will also need change "=" for "= :".

Comment: It is a native query.